# How to use a file from streaming assets on android with Unity?

Tags: c#, android, database, sqlite, unity-game-engine

## Background information

My game is working on iOS, and now trying to update it to work on android. I have a database, Artifact.db, in a StreamingAssets folder, that is built off of SQLite and that has read-only information that I use to get data for the game.

## Issue

The core issue is that the SQlite can't read the data, most likely because its not accessible from what I have been reading through on the docs. I am looking for any solutions but preferably something using the **UnityWebRequest** feature rather than the deprecated **WWW**

#### Working iOS Code

```cs
// Platform dependent code
string filepath = Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/Artifact.db";
string conn = "URI=file:" + filepath;

// SQlite
IDbConnection dbconn;
IDbCommand dbcmd;
IDataReader reader;
dbconn = (IDbConnection)new SqliteConnection(conn);
dbconn.Open();
dbcmd = dbconn.CreateCommand();
string sqlQuery = $"SELECT * FROM Artifact WHERE Rarity='{type}'";
dbcmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;
reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Using this code above on android results in error when doing the reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader(); since it cannot find file.

#### Attempts at Android code

(Since the SQLite code itself is fine I'll only be including the platform-dependent section which deals with finding the file.)

```cs
string DatabaseName = "Artifact.db";
#if UNITY_ANDROID
        string filepath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/Artifact.db";

        if (!File.Exists(filepath))
        {
            Debug.Log("Database not in Persistent path");
            // if it doesn't ->
            // open StreamingAssets directory and load the db ->

            var loadDb = new WWW("jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!/assets/" + DatabaseName);  // this is the path to your StreamingAssets in android
            while (!loadDb.isDone) { }  // CAREFUL here, for safety reasons you shouldn't let this while loop unattended, place a timer and error check
                                        // then save to Application.persistentDataPath
            File.WriteAllBytes(filepath, loadDb.bytes);
        }
        string conn = "URI=file:" + filepath;
#endif
```

I also tried the code from this [unity forum post.](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1695033/loading-asset-in-android-using-streamingassets-and.html) (also modified some things to fit my project)

```cs
 var loadingRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get(Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "Artifact.db"));
// Used "Artifact.db" instead of "your.bytes"
 loadingRequest.SendWebRequest();
 while (!loadingRequest.isDone) {
     if (loadingRequest.isNetworkError || loadingRequest.isHttpError) {
         break;
     }
 }
 if (loadingRequest.isNetworkError || loadingRequest.isHttpError) {
 
 } else {
     File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath , "Artifact.db"), loadingRequest.downloadHandler.data);
// Used "Artifact.db" instead of "your.bytes"
 }

string filepath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/Artifact.db";
string conn = "URI=file:" + filepath;
```

### What I am hoping for

I ideally hope to replicate the iOS code. I think this might mean copying the Artifact.db file to somewhere that is persistent and accessible on android and then using that file location to open the file with SQLite.

Comment: What didn't work with the solutions you tried? In general yes from `Streaming Assets`: `To read streaming Assets on platforms like Android and WebGL
, where you cannot access streaming Asset files directly, use UnityWebRequest. For an example, see Application.streamingAssetsPath.`

Comment: In general you might want to go for [Addressables](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.addressables@1.19/manual/index.html)

Comment: After doing some more digging and debugging on android I believe the issue is I am running Dotnet 4 and my previous SQLite was for dotnet 2 and so the error I was getting on android was unable to load DLL sqlite3.